# What does this message mean at MySQL Workbench startup?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Every time I start MySQL workbench I get this message

[image]

I would like to know what this means and how I can get rid of it... I tried looking on the internet and googling the entire message but no good info came up because you can't see the full message.

Does anyone know what this means and if it's a problem for my database?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench tries to load its workspace data and something is wrong with it. Rename the MySQL Workbench folder (the part you can see in the message) or remove it entirely. Then restart the application and it will recreate all the files.

A side note: often Ctrl+C works in those dialogs, so you can paste the entire content into a text editor.

Comment: in this dialog i can't select the text. i'll try deleting (or moving) it though

Comment: Does this mean i loose my databases?

Comment: No, not at all. This is just workspace data used by MySQL Workbench.

Comment: it has randomly stopped giving the error... guess writing about it on SO fixes it

Answer (score 0):

It's only MySQL workbench which is a GUI for data admin if i'm not mistaken (like navicat). You could simply run the mysql installer and remove/add MySQL workbench again.